# Liferay and more instances

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a simple question about Liferay and more instance of it.

I have my Liferay and I can reach it by myhost.com:8080.

Now I would to create an other instance in Liferay [Liferay - Portal Instances](https://www.liferay.com/it/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen12-portal-instances-0) but I did not understand how I can reach my different instances by browser...

And, How can I configure my different instances about LDAP, CAS... (I would to use the same configuration but if it is not possibile I can copy same configuration for any instances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new instance of Liferay contains a whole new set of data, e.g. LDAP etc. If you want to share the same configuration, user database etc., it might be better to just use different sites. This way you don't duplicate the data at all. Also, you can more seamlessly share the same hostname for logging into different sites.

If you want to address a new instance, you'll see that you need a virtual host name for that instance: Your server will need to be accessible through different hostnames. Any time you access the server under the hostname of your new instance (or any site's virtual host that belongs to that instance) you'll be served content from that instance. If you go through the default virtual host, any of the existing sites' virtual hosts, or an unknown virtual host, you'll get to the default instance.

You can do the separate LDAP configuration either through the UI (as you were used to in the first instance) or through portal-ext.properties. The default portal.properties that comes with Liferay should contain a few examples for instance-specific configuration. Note that not all settings can be done instance-specific in portal-ext.properties. Also, you might need to know that the technical name of an instance (e.g. what you find in code and possibly in portal.properties) is "company" - if you ever stumble upon `companyId`, this is the instance's ID.